# PHP GD - creating favicon.ico for InternetExplorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, gd, ico

I have a very simple PHP script which creates "favicon.ico" form jpg/gif/png uploaded file.

Here is a part of function:

```
$file = 'cache/'.$e .'/'. basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) {  

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor("16", "16");
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, "16", "16", $width, $height);
    $num = rand (1,99999);
    $output = $num."-favicon.ico";
    imagepng($image_p,'dl/'.$output);
    imagedestroy ($im);
    unlink ($file);
    echo 'success';  

}
```

And script works fine! In Chrome, Opera and Firefox generated favicon displays good, as it should do.

But in Interent Explorer 8 - it simply doesn't show up.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just save it as a PNG with the ico extension... I'm guessing Chrome/Opera/Firefox can't read the file, so they decide to open up the file and find out what the actual format is rather than depending on the file extension, while IE doesn't.

However, you will need to find a different solution to save it as an ICO as GD can't do that on its own, you can either try ImageMagick or after a quick Google [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) seems to be able to do it (not tried).

Comment: Thanks! But, is there any solution without ImageMagick ?  Just GD?

Comment: As I said, ImageMagick or phpThumb. I just had a look at the source, at first glance it seems its saving ico files by getting the data from GD.

Comment: To be clear, IE doesn't care about the file extension either.  IE requires that the favicon be an icon.  IE calls ExtractIcon() on the file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648068.aspx) and if that fails, it gives up.